# Definite way to make iOS App validation fail?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Sorry, if there is an obvious answer, but I didn't find anything.

Is there a known way to definitely make the App Store validation process (the one while uploading the App) fail but will still work for Ad-Hoc-Distributions? In code, not info.plist configurations or something.
I tried private APIs such as "[UIApplication addStatusBarImageNamed:....]" but they only seem to be checked during the actual review, that's not what I want.

I'm being a bit paranoid about my builds configurations (and using the wrong one for a live submission) and want to have an "assert" style fail option in there that makes sure I don't upload a build created with a wrong configuration.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different (developer) code signing identity for your "wrong" build configuration. This will make the upload process fail.

Or maybe you could use "invalid" combinations of iOS requirements / supported architectures. For example only support armv7 but minimum require iOS 3.0 - that should be able to compile, but not work on a device.

Comment: It would have to be a distribution code signing identity since the other profile I don't want to mix things up with is my ad-hoc configuration for beta builds. The developer identity is not an issue.
I do already (obviously) use different provisioning profiles (and in fact different identities), however I still like to use the automatic ones since other wise I have to change the build settings every time I add devices to the add-hoc profile and hence the profile changes.

Comment: But that would pass the upload validation, I believe. Also: it still has to actually WORK, this is not a dummy configuration or I would delete it, this is the configuration I actually use for building betas. The reason for this is that I don't want my beta configuration, which has stuff like TestFlight reports and all In-App-Purchases enabled plus some other testing features accidentally submitted to the store.

Answer (score 0):

Add a entitlements file this is signed with a code signing identity of a specific app. Just add this and usually it's not building.